# What's the difference between a classical Hough transform and a multi-scale Hough transform?

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I'm looking at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a) of OpenCV's `cv2.HoughLines()`, and the documentation references a multi-scale Hough transform. What is the difference between a classical Hough transform and a multi-scale Hough transform?

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to understand how the **Hough Transform** algorithm works in general. It is not clear from your question how familiar you are with it.
I recommend to read the following if needed:

1. The description of the algorithm, referred to from the opencv documentation you mentioned in your question: [Hough Transform](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hough.htm).
2. OpenCV's tutorial for [Hough Line Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d3/de6/tutorial_js_houghlines.html).

In a nutshell, the **classical** algorithm is composed of the following elements
(all the angles are represented in degrees rather than radians only for convenience):

1. A line is parametrized by it's perpendicular distance from the origin (**ρ** - rho),
   and the angle formed by this perpendicular line (**θ** - theta).
2. The `rho` and `theta` parameters of [`cv::HoughLines`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a) actually determine the **resolution** of ρ and θ.
   Since the distance is bound by the image diagonal size, and the angle is 0..180,
   we can create a matrix of all the combinations of distances and angles (according to the resolution). This is called the **accumulator**.
   E.g.: if image diagonal is 100 and `rho` parameter is 20, we'll get the following ρ values in the matrix: 0,20,40,60,80,100.
   same applies for the angle. Each cell in the accumulator matrix represents one potential line (with a specific ρ,θ) .
3. The input image must be a binary mask. We traverse all the "lit" pixels.
   Each pixel can belong to multiple lines (according to various ρ and θ). We increment each cell in the **accumulator** that correspond to any of these lines. This is like **voting** for it.
4. Eventually we pick the lines with the highest votes (depending on the `threshold`) as the output.

The **multi-scale** version adds the following, to form an iterative process:

1. Instead of applying a single resolution for ρ, `srn` parameter determines the divisor for the distance resolution.
2. Similarly instead of applying a single resolution for θ, `stn` parameter determines the divisor for the angle resolution.
3. There are also `min_theta` and `max_theta` parameters that can limit the range of the angles we track.

In general the multi-scale version can offer better result (due to trying more resolutions), for the price of heavier computation.
I haven't found formal documentation about the exact way this iterative process is done.
But from the comments in the opencv source code, it seems like at least 2 iterations are done: One coarse (with `rho` and `theta`) and one fine (with `rho/srn` and `theta/stn`).

I recommend you to try both and compare result quality and processing time in your specific case.

Note that there is also a probabalistic version - see [`cv::HoughLinesP`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb)