# How to find horizontal Lines on image?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV. I'm working on a picture where I need to identify the horizontal lines on the meter image, but every time I attempt to obtain it, it just finds some of the lines and I can't get all of them.

[image: meter Image]

below is my code:

```
print("[INFO] Converting to Gray...\n")
gray = cv.cvtColor(image,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print("[INFO] Converted to Gray.\n")

print("[INFO] Applying Thresholding...\n")
thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
print("[INFO] Threshold Applied.\n")

# Detect horizontal lines
print("[INFO] Creating Horizontal Kernal.\n")
horizontal_kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (40,1))
        
detect_horizontal = cv.morphologyEx(thresh, cv.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in cnts:
   M = cv.moments(c)
      if M['m00'] != 0:
         cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
         cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00']) 
         cv.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)

cv.imshow('result', resize(result,p=.35))
```

I want to obtain all lines on the image and their x, and y coordinate positions.

Comment: See some info about hough transform and its parameters in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72115574/whats-the-difference-between-a-classical-hough-transform-and-a-multi-scale-houg/72456927#72456927.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, `result` is not defined

Comment: you shouldn't even try to identify that scale. it's blurry and irrelevant anyway. fix the tube and the camera. manually annotate the scale in one image. use that information from then on. -- your picture is utterly unsuitable for any CV or measurements. the tube is visibly misaligned -- you appear to try to measure gas flow. there are proper sensors for that. it's a terrible idea to use a webcam to solve this visually. very bad idea. terrible. so many proper approaches and solutions exist for the task.

Comment: As mentioned your image is terrible, also your threshold just returns a black white rectangle

Comment: Only the line marked 25 is horizontal. The rest is increasingly sloped because of perspective distortion. But I have to agree with Christoph here, why try to solve an already solved problem, making it more complex by adding a camera?